# Table not found in hive when querying "select * from tab1"

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am not able to see the contents of a hive table 'result1' & 'result2' created by Spark in hive shell. I am able to query these two tables and see the results in the spark program.

In the hive shell. I am able to run the same query "select * from tab1" without any issues since 'tab1' is created in hive shell.

When I run the below command I am able to see the warehouse directories present for all the three tables.

hdadmin@ubuntu:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
2020-06-19 11:29:10,465 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 3 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hdadmin supergroup          0 2020-06-17 12:40 /user/hive/warehouse/result1
drwxr-xr-x   - hdadmin supergroup          0 2020-06-18 11:07 /user/hive/warehouse/result2
drwxr-xr-x   - hdadmin supergroup          0 2020-06-19 11:27 /user/hive/warehouse/tab1

Any help on this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me guess : Hive 3 with different namespaces for Hive databases and Spark databases, unless you change a Spark property to use the same NS?

Comment: Could you please provide details on where to change the spark property to use the same namespace as hive?

Comment: Cloud you please provide **some information** about the distribution/version of your Hadoop / Hive / Spark components? Maybe an Azure HDInsight setup, based on the `hdamin` account?

Comment: Versions: Spark 3.0.0 hive 3.1.2 hadoop 3.2.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773385/spark-sql-cant-find-table-in-hive-in-hdp

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-databases-are-not-visible-in-Spark-session/td-p/239786

Comment: I am able to query the hive tables in spark program but not in hive session. I am getting the above error when I query the table in hive shell.